# Using PyDrake AutoDiff to compute the Jacobian of a vector in some frame

Tags: drake

Suppose I have a vector `n_F` which is fixed in a frame `F` (for example, a normal vector on the surface of a fingertip that is fixed in the local fingertip frame). The vector `n_W(q)` depends on the configuration via the expression `n_W = R_WF @ n_F`, where the rotation matrix `R_WF` depends on the configuration via the forward kinematics map.

My question is how to recover the Jacobian `Dn_W` of `n_W` with respect to `q` (which will be some 3 by n matrix) using Drake's AutoDiff. I figure there must be some internal implementation of this since constraints between two angles in different frames are enforceable during IK, and I'm assuming IK is solved with a gradient-based solver. However, I'm having trouble working with this since AutoDiffXd seems to only work on scalar functions.

Alternatively, if there's some simple way to express this Jacobian using available Drake functions, that would also suffice for my application - I haven't been able to work out a clean expression for this by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I have a (non-AutoDiff) solution currently implemented that does not involve rotations.

Let `J0` and `J1` denote the translational velocity Jacobians of the origin of the frame `F` and of the vector `n_F` both expressed in frame `F`, where the velocities are measured and expressed in the world frame. Then, The desired Jacobian `Dn_W` is simply `J1 - J0`.